# Url-rewriting using .htaccess is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like my url which is: `http://localhost/slide-form/ad_posted.php?title=Cow%20Buffalo%20Gopal-1426356570`

to look like : `http://localhost/slide-form/ad_posted/title/Cow%20Buffalo%20Gopal-1426356570/`

The below is the rule i have added in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ad_posted/title/(.*)/ ad_posted.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ad_posted/title/(.*) ad_posted.php?title=$1                 
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
</IfModule>
```

But I see no changes in my url. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you actually reffer to this link: http://localhost/slide-form/ad_posted/title/Cow%20Buffalo%20Gopal-1426356570/

Comment: you got to make the link towards the /ad_posted/title/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in `/slide-form/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /slide-form/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ad_posted\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ad_posted/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^ad_posted/title/(.+)/?$ ad_posted.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are two things need to attention:**

1. Make sure you apache or other web server is already opened rewrite
   module.
2. Check your configuration settings and ensure the directory where 
   .htaccess file located have the overwrite permission.

Like following settings:

[image]